# How do i discover what the Task name is from the Task list workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have a primary workflow that kicks off a To-Do task.

the task goes to a task list that is shared with many other tasks.

my problem is that i'm only allowed from the secondary task workflow to know the original workflow name, id or list id.

i need a way to scope down to what the name of the To-Do task is.

any way to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being incredibly simple. Just use Task Name = the title of the To Do Task.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say before creating the To Do task, create a variable to create a unique task name. Then you can query the Task list by that unique name.

Something like: To-Do task for [someuser] in regards to [current item id]